# Could not convert string to float: 'Neudorf'

Tags: python, databricks

I have a dataframe df which contains a float column num. It looks like
None
0.00
...
0.00
0.00
0.00

In data frame num is in object data type. So I'm trying to convert it to float data type in databricks Runtime 7. I'm using following command

```
df['num']=df['num'].astype(float)
```

But I'm getting error message

```
could not convert string to float: 'Neudorf'
```

Can you help me to resolve the issue?

Comment: You have this string somewhere in that column you are typecasting.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that somewhere in df you have got a non-numeric element, specifically an element with the value "Neudorf" where there should be a number.
So you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
df['num'] = pd.to_numeric(df['num'], errors='coerce')
```

For more info and a lovely tutorial on this, take a look at this:
https://datatofish.com/convert-string-to-float-dataframe/

Also check out this for what other options there are for errors, other than coerce:

Documentation for to_numeric():
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_numeric.html